# How can console application Add in Windows 10 core out package?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

How can console application Add in Windows 10 core out package?Add Console application as part of .ffu image.
is there any way to convert this console ".exe" to .appx package or any other packages that can be a part of IOT image?
how to add as a startup console application with console UI is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console application are supported but only apparently in C++. Windows IoT Core can be configured for either [*Headed* or *Headless* Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/headlessmode).Headed mode is defined by the presence of UI,but console app has no gui, it is a command line based executable application.So, you can not add a console application as a startup with console UI displayed. But you can create a [*Background Application*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/backgroundapplications),and then add in *.ffu image, please refer to this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/iot/deploy-your-app-with-a-standard-board).